# Pass iterator instead of container

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

Currently, I'm stuck with some code like `fooA()` (don't mind the body) which expects a specific container, say `vector<double>`, as argument.

```
double fooA(std::vector<double> const& list)
{
    return list[0];
}
```

Now, I want to generalize and use iterators instead:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
double fooB(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    return *first;
}
```

How to state that `fooB()` requires the iterator to iterate over `double`?

Someone might pass a `vector<string>::iterator` or, even worse as it might compile without a warning, a `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: Maybe you mean that you need to indicate the iterator is required to iterate over double?

Comment: Heh, this can be done, but it's not pretty.  I recommend just putting in a comment, since the return type will force that it the iterator type at least converts to a `double` anyways.

Comment: `double` instead of `int` of course. I corrected that, thanks. My "real world return type" does not depend on the iterator...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C++03:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

template<typename InputIterator>
typename boost::enable_if<
    boost::is_same<
        typename boost::remove_cv<
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
        >::type,
        double // expected value_type
    >,
    double     // fooB return type
>::type
fooB(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    return *first;
}
```

Another C++03 solution which doesn't use Boost, but will likely produce much uglier errors when passing an invalid type:

```
#include <iterator>

void fooB_helper(double) { }
template<typename T> void fooB_helper(T const&);

template<typename InputIterator>
double fooB(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    fooB_helper(typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type());
    return *first;
}
```

For C++11 you can use expression SFINAE instead of `enable_if`, or you can use `static_assert` instead of SFINAE altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Boost/C++11, you might be able to get away with this approach:

```
template<typename B, template<typename A1, typename B1> class Container>
double fooB(typename Container<int, B>::iterator first,
   typename Container<int, B>::iterator last)
{
  return 0;
}
```

to call:

```
vector<int> a;
fooB<vector<int>::allocator_type, vector>(a.begin(), a.end());
```

A bit ugly, but works :)

Also: non-portable as the std collection implementations canhave more than two template parameters (the second one is an allocator with a default value)

Comment: The stdlib collections have _at least_ two template arguments, but they are allowed to have more as long as the additional ones have defaults. I.e., this code is not portable.